# LeetCode 124: Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum 2

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, programming-challenge

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem. If you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

Given a non-empty binary tree, find the maximum path sum.

For this problem, a path is defined as any sequence of nodes from some starting node to any node in the tree along the parent-child connections. The path must contain at least one node and does not need to go through the root.

#### Example 1:

```
Input: [1,2,3]

       1
      / \
     2   3

Output: 6
```

#### Example 2:

```
Input: [-10,9,20,null,null,15,7]

   -10
   / \
  9  20
    /  \
   15   7

Output: 42
```

#### Inputs

```
[1,2,3]
[-10,9,20,null,null,15,7]
[-10,9,20,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,7]
[-10,9,20,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,720,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,7]
[-10,9,20,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,720,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,7999999,20,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,720,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,7]
```

#### Outputs

```
6
42
66
791
8001552
```

#### Code

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution:
    def maxPathSum(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        def depth_first_search(node: TreeNode) -> int:
            if not node:
                return 0
            left_sum = depth_first_search(node.left)
            right_sum = depth_first_search(node.right)
            if not left_sum or left_sum < 0:
                left_sum = 0
            if not right_sum or right_sum < 0:
                right_sum = 0
            self.sum = max(self.sum, left_sum + right_sum + node.val)
            return max(left_sum, right_sum) + node.val

        self.sum = float('-inf')
        depth_first_search(root)
        return self.sum
```

#### References

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/discuss/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/solution/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Unnecessary checks in `depth_first_search()`

The function `depth_first_search()` always returns an integer value, never `None`. So the check for a partial sum being `None` or `< 0` can be rewritten using `max()`:

```
left_sum = max(0, depth_first_search(node.left))
right_sum = max(0, depth_first_search(node.right))
```